# Frames with pict_type=I yet key_frame=0

Tags: ffmpeg, keyframes

I am trying to exrtact key frame information from a mp4 video using ffprobe with the command:

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames FILE_NAME  2>/dev/null
```

I am getting the list of all frames. From these, I searched for frames with pict_type=I to recognise I-frames. However, there were about 10 of the total 700 I frames which had

```
media_type=video
key_frame=0
pict_type=I
```

What are these frames? If these are I-frames what makes them not a key_frame?

Comment: What is the definition of a "key frame' in this context?

Comment: I am not actually sure. From what I knew, it is the I-frame, but from the ffprobe output, there are I-frames which are not key_frames. That is what my question is.

Comment: Without context, or a definition from the ffprobe docs, there's no way to know. But I have to ask -- if you don't know what they are, why are you looking for them?

Answer (score 4):

This means although it is and I-frame, the decoder might still use/need previously sent frames for decoding. In contrast if `key_frame=1` this would be an **IDR-Frame** (Instantaneous Decoder Refresh).

Citing from  Ian E. G. Richardson's *H.264 and MPEG-4 Video Compression*:

> An encoder sends an IDR (Instantaneous Decoder Refresh) coded picture
> (made up of I- or SI-slices) to clear the contents of the reference
> picture buffer. On receiving an IDR coded picture, the decoder marks
> all pictures in the reference buffer as ‘unused for reference’. All
> subsequent transmitted slices can be decoded without reference to any
> frame decoded prior to the IDR picture. The first picture in a coded
> video sequence is always an IDR picture.

This may have impact on random access to a video. Simply said, IDR frames make random access more robust.